# Delete to end of command line in Vim

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, vimrc

I like to use shell style shortcuts in insert and command-line mode, such as CTRL-K to delete to end of line. This mapping works in insert mode:

```
inoremap <C-K> <C-O>D
```

But I can't figure out an equivalent for command-line mode. Any ideas?

I'm using Vrapper in case it matters.

Comment: `SHIFT + D` or what did you mean?

Comment: Right, but that only works in normal mode. In command-line mode it inserts a D character.

Comment: "_shell style shortcuts_". Do you mean emacs-mode line editing, as in `bash`'s `set -o emacs`? If so, why not just use `emacs` instead of `vi`(`m`) and be done with it?

Comment: The thing is CTRL-K is not just used in emacs and bash. On Mac OS it deletes to EOL in almost every app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### alternative approach

The [`:help command-line-window`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#command-line-window) is one of the lesser-known features of Vim. You can enter it with `<C-f>` by default when you're already on the commandline, or `q:` from normal mode. As in any other Vim buffer, you can edit the current or previous command-lines using Vim commands, and press `<Enter>` to execute and close it. In it, you can use `D` just like anywhere else.

#### mapping

If you want that functionality directly in the command-line itself, you can define this simple mapping:

```
cnoremap <C-k> <C-\>e(strpart(getcmdline(), 0, getcmdpos() - 1))<CR>
```

Note that your suggested left-hand side clobbers the useful *digraphs* entry.

#### plugin

My [CmdlineSpecialEdits plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5865) has (among many others) a `CTRL-G D` mapping that removes all characters between the cursor position and the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
:,.d$
```

To delete from the cursor to the end of file.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Nope. I want to delete what's on the command line, in command-line mode.